# Is there a way to store both a pandas dataframe and separate string var in the same SQLite table?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

Disclaimer: This is my first time posting a question here, so I apologize if I didn't post this properly.

I recently started learning how to use SQLite in python. As the title suggests, I have a python object with a string and a pandas dataframe attributes and want to know if/how I can add both of these to the same SQLite table. Below is the code I have thus far. The *mydb.db* file gets created successfully, but on insert I get the following error message:

**sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter :df- probably unsupported type.**

I know you can use `df.to_sql('mydbs', conn)` to store a pandas dataframe in an SQL table, but this wouldn't seem to allow for an additional string to be added to the same table and then retrieved separately from the dataframe. Any solutions or alternative suggestions are appreciated.

Python Code:

```py
# Python 3.7
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import myclass

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE mydbs (
             name text,
             df blob
             )""")

conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO mydbs VALUES (:name, :df)", {'name': myclass.name, 'df': myclass.df})

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to store a dataframe in an SQL table 'cell'. This is a bit odd, since sql is used for storing tables of data... and a dataframe is something that arguably should be stored as a table on its own (hence the built in pandas function). To accomplish what you want specifically, you could pickle the dataframe and store it

```
import codecs
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": range(5), "bar": range(5, 10)})
pickled = codecs.encode(pickle.dumps(df), "base64").decode()
```

df

```
   foo  bar
0    0    5
1    1    6
2    2    7
3    3    8
4    4    9
```

Store & Retrieve:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE mydbs (
             name text,
             df text
             )""")

c.execute("INSERT INTO mydbs VALUES (:name, :df)", {'name': 'name', 'df': pickled})
conn.commit()

c.execute('SELECT * FROM mydbs')
result = c.fetchall()
unpickled = pickle.loads(codecs.decode(result[0][1].encode(), "base64"))
conn.close()
```

unpickled

```
   foo  bar
0    0    5
1    1    6
2    2    7
3    3    8
4    4    9
```

If you wanted to store the dataframe as an sql table (which imo makes more sense and is simpler) and you needed to have a name with it you could just add a column 'name' to the df:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": range(5), "bar": range(5, 10)})
```

df

```
   foo  bar
0    0    5
1    1    6
2    2    7
3    3    8
4    4    9
```

Add name column, then save to db and retrieve:

```
df['name'] = 'the df name'

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
df.to_sql('users', con=engine)
r = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
r = pd.read_sql('users', con=engine)
```

r

```
   index  foo  bar         name
0      0    0    5  the df name
1      1    1    6  the df name
2      2    2    7  the df name
3      3    3    8  the df name
4      4    4    9  the df name
```

But even that method may not be ideal, since you are effectively adding an extra column of data for each df, and this could get costly if you are working on a large project where database size is a factor, and maybe even speed (although SQL is quite fast). In this case, it may be best to use relational tables. For this I refer you [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/11/python-sqlite-tutorial-relational/) since there is no point re-writing the code here. Using a relational model would be the most 'proper' solution imo, since it fully embodies the purpose of SQL.

Comment: Thank you that's pretty much what I was looking for! I know it was kind of an odd request I just needed a way to store the pairing of the string name and the associated dataframe and this seems to work well. I'm not too worried about the size it's a small dataset.